# T-SQL DYNAMIC PIVOT TABLE wont execute

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, pivot-table

```
DECLARE @FirstDayOfWeek DATETIME

SELECT @FirstDayOfWeek = 
  COALESCE(
cast(@FirstDayOfWeek AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ',[' + cast(@FirstDayOfWeek AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ']',
'[' + cast(@FirstDayOfWeek AS VARCHAR(MAX))+ ']'
  )
FROM [Calendar] c
        LEFT JOIN Stores s ON c.FirstDayOfMonth = s.Validfrom
        left join POSProductDivPeriod pos ON c.Period = pos.Period

DECLARE @PivotTableSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @PivotTableSQL = N'
  SELECT *
 FROM (
SELECT
  YEAR(FirstDayOfWeek) [Year],
  @FirstDayOfWeek,
 pos.quantity
FROM [Calendar] c
  LEFT JOIN Stores s ON c.FirstDayOfMonth = s.Validfrom
        left join POSProductDivPeriod pos ON c.Period = pos.Period
  ) AS PivotData
  PIVOT (
SUM(pos.quantity)
FOR @FirstDayOfWeek IN (
  ' +CAST(@FirstDayOfWeek AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '
)
  ) AS PivotTable
'

EXECUTE(@PivotTableSQL)
```

when i run all of this i get command complete 
when i run execute i get must declare scarlar 
im trying to run my code for my pivot table and for it to execute right after

any ideas ?

Comment: The problem is pretty clear you are trying to use  variable `@FirstDayOfWeek` in your dynamic sql, dynamic sql has its own scope and any variables declared outside of its scope are not visible to dynamic sql. `@FirstDayOfWeek` needs to be concatenated to the dynamic sql.

Comment: What does it say when you do PRINT @PivotTableSQL ?